# ReactJS - What instead of JWT to keep session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, session

For some time I have been writing an application based on this tutorial:

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example

My application is already much more developed, it uses other rest API servers, etc. Currently, after positive authentication, a JWT token is sent to the client, which is stored in localStorage. But!
I need to add such functionality: the assumption is that only one user can use one account at a time.

There are two solutions:
a) when the user is logged in, he logs out in the previous place after logging in on the other device/browser.
b) when user trying log in another device/browser get a throw for example "Client already login"

So, From what I learned, I can't do it using JWT. My question is :

What can I use instead of JWT to handle the session because I think it's about?
Thanks.

EDIT : My authenticate funtion from server side :

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
console.log(username + " " + password);
const user = await User.findOne({ username });
if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.hash)) {
    const { hash, ...userWithoutHash } = user.toObject();
    const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user.id }, config.secret, { expiresIn: 300 });
    return {
        ...userWithoutHash,
        token
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You may use a more traditional session ID based authentication approach.  When a user logs in, a session ID (something along the lines of a UUID) gets generated.  Then, using the user ID as a key, the session ID gets stored in a hashmap on the server.  In all subsequent login attempts, the session ID in the map would be overwritten for the same user.

I suggest kicking out any other session during subsequent login for usability reasons.  Imagine logging into your application from some device, but suddenly getting pulled into a meeting somewhere.  Now, if we don't kick out previous sessions during login, any attempt on your part to login from a different device would fail, and you would be forced to wait to be able to login.

Note that once the new session ID has been recorded in the hashmap, any access attempts by the first device using the old session ID would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT to handle the session itself.

But to handle multiple logins to a single account, you can for example add a `locked` attribute to your `users` table in your database, provided you have such thing in your architecture. This would allow you to lock your session.

**This solution only makes sense if you want to totally lock your session until logout** (and not be able to login from another device for instance). If that is not your intention, I recommend Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

Example:

```
users || id | name | locked
----- || -- + ---- + ------
      ||  1 | John | 0
      ||  2 | Bob  | 0
```

Then, we could imagine your session handling to be as such (simple example for an Express app, but see it as pseudo code):

```
database.query("SELECT locked FROM users WHERE name = $1", [name])
.then((data) => {
    if (data.locked === 1) { 
        res.status(403).json();
    } else {
        database.query("UPDATE users SET locked = 1 WHERE name = $1", [name])
        .then(() => {
            // Define token key and object for jwt
            // ...
            var token = jwt.sign(...);
            res.status(200).cookie('token', token).json();
        });
    }
});
```

And then, when a user logs out or is logged out by an expired jwt token, you call another endpoint of your API and you set the `locked` attribute to 0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thinking about it, In my case better is block other login attempts via the same user but what about if client dont logout from my website, but for example he clear her browser (cookies etc) ?

Comment: You could automatically unlock the session after a certain time, or set an expiration date for your JWT that you store in a database, and then run a cronjob that checks for expiration dates and unlocks all sessions for which the expiration dates has passed.